# While installing Android Emulator (SDK) I am having an issue with the /opt directory

Tags: command-line, android, ubuntu-sdk, android-emulator

While installing the Android Emulator (SDK) by following [this tutorial](http://www.2daygeek.com/install-sdk-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/) and applying these commands:

```
$ cd /opt
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
$ sudo tar -zxvf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
$ cd /android-sdk-linux/tools
$ ./android
```

I got past the first two commands fine then when entering the third command:

```
$ cd /android-sdk-linux/tools
```

I got this error:

```
bash: cd: /android-sdk-linux/tools: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: With reference to your other question (not being able to find the SDK after step 6 in your tutorial) I edited my answer slightly - I think you just need to run `android` again. Please comment if not, and we'll work it out (the tutorial is quite unclear I think)

Comment: yes i am still having so many issues, it seems the more i try to follow the advice the more mistakes i make...i'm sorry for being such a noob but i'm honestly trying my best to problem solve, any ideas of what i should provide you with to help you make suggestions?

Comment: don't worry :) what happens when you run the `android` file again? (see the end of my answer)

Comment: this is what i get -  Bash: ./android: No such file or directory

Comment: did you `cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command is incorrect. When you have completed the previous commands you are still in the directory `/opt` and `android-sdk-linux` is a subdirectory of it, and `tools` is a subdirectory of `android-sdk-linux`, so you cd to it like this:

```
cd android-sdk-linux/tools
```

without the leading `/`, which signifies the root directory right at the top. You can see that `/android-sdk-linux/tools`does not exist if you `ls` the root directory

```
ls /
```

see? no `android-sdk-linux` here. But you see `opt` which is where you were before... That's why its location is `/opt`

If you are not in the `/opt` directory, (for example you opened a new terminal) you need to use the full path

```
cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

The directory may possibly have a different name so do

```
cd /opt; ls
```

and you will see, if not exactly, then something like `android-sdk-linux` use the correct name:

```
cd android-sdk-linux; ls
```

now you should see `tools`

```
cd tools
```

and now you can run your executable.

Note: If you already closed it after step 6, to progress to step 7 in the tutorial, you should repeat the last two steps:

```
cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
./android
```

Comment: @InigoMontoya no worries :) maybe you can help me with Android SDK later on, I need help with that myself!

Comment: I'd be glad  to help with anything within my capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `ls` to see what folders are there in the directory and then replace that `/android-sdk-linux/tools` with something like `/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux/tools` change that `android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux` according to the folder you find upon doing a `ls` whose name probably will begining with android.

Further Note:
Here `cd` means change directory just like you normally do by double clicking on the folder icon , thats just the command line way.
If you are using the default terminal than you can just type `cd` and drag that folder from file manager to the terminal and press `enter` to enter it.
Thats just a simple trick which can help you a lot!

Cheers