# After installing the Android Emulator, I can't find it anywhere

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

I followed the tutorial [on this page](http://www.2daygeek.com/install-sdk-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/).

After completing step 6 (installing the packages) I cannot open Android Studio to get to Android Device Manager. I have looked everywhere for it and have no idea where to find it or how to start it. How can I open it?

Comment: Thank you , i have searched in the applications and there is nothing there, nothing appears when i type it in the search box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) (Step 5 of the accepted answer)

Comment: 1. You do not need Android Studio to run an Android AVD. 2. You can install Android Studio using Ubuntu Make (recommended method). 3. The tutorial you linked, in fact, does not install Android Studio, but it installs the Android SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While installing Android Emulator (SDK) I am having an issue with the /opt directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/804310/while-installing-android-emulator-sdk-i-am-having-an-issue-with-the-opt-direc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot open Android Studio

The tutorial you linked to never mentions Android Studio. In fact, it is not a tutorial about installing the Android Studio IDE. It is a tutorial about installing the Android SDK which you can use to run Android AVDs.

> to get to Android Device Manager

You do not need Android Studio (the IDE) to run the Device Manager. The device manager can be opened through the SDK Manager by running the `android` executable, which is located in the directory where you installed the SDK.

According to the tutorial, you installed it into:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

(There is an error on step 3 in the tutorial which mentions `/android-sdk-linux/tools` instead, but whatever)

For this reason, you will be able to run the SDK Manager like this:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

When the SDK Manager opens, use the menu:

> *Tools → Manage AVDs...*

Create one or more AVDs and then run them. You should **definitely** choose to create them with x86 ABI, because those using the ARM architecture will be very slow since the CPU needs to be emulated.

The system images for Android must be installed through the SDK Manager that you opened before. You need to close the AVD Manager to use the SDK Manager.

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that you can [install Android-x86 in VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/a/328243/271) if you just want to run an Android OS.

Comment: I tried the android-x86 sometime back but the speeds were rather slow and opted for android debugging bridge , for your case as of now is the performance good

Comment: This question is a follow-on from [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/804310/while-installing-android-emulator-sdk-i-am-having-an-issue-with-the-opt-direc/804324#804324). I think the OP already reached that point, though the tutorial  is really unclear... I don't think I have enough space on my system to test it myself...

Comment: @Zanna ah! Then I don't see the point of *this* question. You have already instructed the OP on how to run the SDK Manager. I am flagging this Q as duplicate.

Comment: But they are still stuck... Ahhh I think I get it. I thought it was just the installation script... I guess they closed it and need to run it again but it has no `.desktop` file and isn't in the PATH...

Comment: @Zanna, even if it is not in the path, your answer clearly provides the solution. I still don't see the point in asking the same thing again.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course, and they would be able to run it by doing the same thing again, but I think they do not realise that they need to do that. Have I reached the same page as you, or am I still confused?

Comment: @Zanna I see what you mean. I believe it should have been a comment on your (correct and complete) A rather than a new Q.

Comment: Let me see if I can make enough sense of the tutorial to make a minor clarifying edit to my answer there so this question can be disposed of without leaving the OP in a muddle. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: i am sorry if i made a mistake, i am still so very new, but i appreciate your patience.  I am stuck but i am attempting to try your solutions.  thank you, if i have done something wrong , please tell me.

Comment: @InigoMontoya did the answer solve your problem? If not and it needs improvement I could edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is starting when you start the installation executable. If i recall correctly, after downloading `Android Studio`, you have to unzip it and run `<android folder>/studio.sh`. This is the same `sh` that will run `Android Studio` for you. If this option is not working for you, you can always download the complete archive of `Android Studio` + `SDK` in android studio website and save yourself the lines in terminal.
[Adnroid Studio+SDK download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Comment: Did you check the linked page? The OP did not install Android Studio at all.

Comment: Android studio installer has emulator included in the installation...

Comment: OK, so what? That does not answer the question "why can't I find Android Studio?" → "Because you never installed it (and you don't need it for the emulator)".

Comment: So basically I did answer it

Comment: «If i recall correctly» «If this option is not working» Quite a few ifs in the same answer. Your post is probably much more suited as a comment than an answer. As a general rule, if a post contains "If" or "maybe"/"could"/"might" then it's usually a comment. It can become an answer after the OP has replied and confirmed.

Comment: hello friend, i am reading the comments now and trying to ascertain what i should do, i will follow the ideas mentioned and get back to you with results, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find the diretory location of android studio by:

```
sudo find / -iname studio.sh
```

Once you locate the directory go to it by:

```
cd ~android studio directory~
```

Once you are in this directory change permisions of the `studio.sh` file:

```
sudo chmod +x ./studio.sh
```

Now run the `studio.sh` bash file :

```
./studio.sh
```